# SQLite3, match and regexp

Tags: regex, sqlite, match

Is there a way to combine the `MATCH` and `REGEXP` operators in an SQLite3 statement?

eg. I suspect not but,

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE name MATCH REGEXP '[ _]Smith[ _];'
```

Comment: Can you give an example name?

Comment: Why not just regexp? regexp do more.

Comment: REGEXP is too slow, I need some indexing such as that offered with FTS3 and MATCH.

Comment: ugh.. Did you realize mixing two give you the slower of two?     -- you won't want to combine them.

Comment: That's probably true - I'd still like to know though.